# React state value with comma being ignored

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use [react-number-format](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format) component along with Material UI to create formatted text fields but when I update the state by adding a comma to the number,  the number after the comma is added to the number like (if `number = 5`, when adding `5,5` stays on `55`).

This is an example of how the code looks like:

```js
<NumberFormat
    label="Number"
    variant="outlined"  
    prefix="$ "                            
    value={number}
    thousandSeparator="." 
    decimalSeparator=","
    decimalScale={2}    
    onValueChange={n => setNumber(n.value)}
/>
```

I was trying looking for a workaround and I found that `react-number-format` has nothing to do with this "issue" or whatever I am doing in the wrong way. I have created a usual text input with the same attributes and methods and it behaves like the previous one.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import NumberFormat from "react-number-format";

export default function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(number)
  }, [number]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NumberFormat
        label="Number"
        variant="outlined"  
        prefix="$ "                            
        value={number}
        thousandSeparator="." 
        decimalSeparator=","
        decimalScale={2}    
        onValueChange={n => setNumber(n.value)}
      />
      <input value={number} onChange={e => setNumber(e.target.value)} />
      <input />
    </div>
  );
```

I wasn't able to find any answer or workaround for this stuff.

This is a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-bash-er0re) playground to see the error live.

Comment: It's not set as a number, is a string value.

Comment: It looks like your thousandsSeparator and decimalSeparator are backwards. Changing those in your sandbox seems to work, if I understand the problem

Comment: @BrianThompson is correct, you need to switch to two separators to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Brian Thompson, I guess you mean that I should use `thousandSeparator=","` and `decimalSeparator="."`. But here in my country we use a dot to separate thousands and comma for decimals.

Comment: not sure why, but I had to access to `number.floatValue` in order to set the state.

Comment: Oh interesting, didn't know that was different regionally